# VB.Net why is my marshaled structure updated when passed ByVal but not when passed ByRef

Tags: .net, structure, marshalling, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have been struggling for hours to get some calls into a system dll to work. I finally figured out how to get it to work, but I dont understand why.

I needed to pass a structure to the library function `midiOutPrepareHeader` and that structure contains a pointer to a buffer I allocate and some flags that the library sets. In the declaration I originally had **`ByRef`**`lpMidiOutHdr As IntPtr`. There were no obvious errors but the following function call always reported that the buffer hadn't been "prepared" (the prepared flag wasn't set). When I eventually changed it to **`ByVal`**`lpMidiOutHdr As IntPtr` the copy of the structure after the call had the flag set and the subsequent function worked.

(I have removed the code I used to inspect the structure and find out what was going on but basically this used `PtrToStructure` to "unmarshal" the data so I could inspect it).

```
Private Declare Function fmidiOutPrepareHeader Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "midiOutPrepareHeader" (ByVal hMidiOut As Integer, ByVal lpMidiOutHdr As IntPtr, ByVal uSize As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function fmidiOutUnprepareHeader Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "midiOutUnprepareHeader" (ByVal hMidiOut As Integer, ByVal lpMidiOutHdr As IntPtr, ByVal uSize As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function fmidiOutLongMsg Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "midiOutLongMsg" (ByVal hMidiOut As Integer, ByVal lpMidiOutHdr As IntPtr, ByVal uSize As Integer) As Integer

Public Function midiOutGetDevCaps(ByVal uDeviceID As Integer, ByRef lpCaps As MIDIOUTCAPS) As Integer
    Return fmidiOutGetDevCaps(uDeviceID, lpCaps, Marshal.SizeOf(lpCaps))
End Function

Public Function midiOutLongMsg(ByVal hMidiOut As Integer, ByRef MidiOutHdr As MIDIHDR, ByRef MidiOutData As Byte()) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer
    MidiOutHdr.lpData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(MidiOutHdr.dwBufferLength)     'allocate unmanaged memory for the data to be copied into. Set the header to point to it
    Marshal.Copy(MidiOutData, 0, MidiOutHdr.lpData, MidiOutHdr.dwBytesRecorded)
    Dim unmanagedHeader As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(MidiOutHdr))
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(MidiOutHdr, unmanagedHeader, True)
    result = fmidiOutPrepareHeader(hMidiOut, unmanagedHeader, Marshal.SizeOf(MidiOutHdr))
    result = fmidiOutLongMsg(hMidiOut, unmanagedHeader, Marshal.SizeOf(MidiOutHdr))
    result = fmidiOutUnprepareHeader(hMidiOut, unmanagedHeader, Marshal.SizeOf(MidiOutHdr))
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedHeader)
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(MidiOutHdr.lpData)
    MidiOutHdr.lpData = 0
    Return result
End Function
```

Can anyone explain why I get data back fromt the dll when passing by value but not when passing by reference?

Many thanks.
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `midiOutPrepareHeader` method's second parameter is a "Pointer to a MIDIHDR structure that identifies the buffer to be prepared".  Your `IntPtr` is that pointer.  By declaring the parameter `ByRef` you were passing a pointer to the pointer instead of passing the pointer itself.